# How to launch eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=2
/usr/local/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.dist/eclipse_1408.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 428003
-clean
-initialize
-vm /usr/local/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
```

So java -version give path not found. I have tried the following:
Edit ~/.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/environment bash.bashrc files and add to them the following

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_15
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_15
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

In addition, I also manually added the java bin directory to PATH. I have restarted my computer several times but I still get

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's the output when you run `java -version` from the command-line?

Answer (score 1):

Put `$JAVA_HOME/bin` at the *front* of your path. Don't put `$JRE_HOME/bin` in your path at all.

Currently you're picking up some other file (probably a symlink) in `/usr/local/bin`, because that directory appears first in your path.

I'm not sure why you installed Java in `/usr/lib`; is that where the Ubuntu installer puts it? If yes, then I would expect `/usr/local/bin/java` to point to a valid file. You might want to double-check that.

And finally (the reason I asked for the output of `java -version`), make sure that you're running an x64 version of the JVM, because that's the version of Eclipse that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

So where do you have Java installed, to `/usr/local/bin/java` or to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_15/bin/java`?
Do a `ls -l /usr/local/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_15/bin/java`, what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to update the references to your compiler path, since your ubuntu is not recognizing the path where you installed jdk or jre:

Use this command to see what are the java versions in your computer:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Then if necessary, update the location of the jdk and jre you're using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6.31-oracle/bin/javac" 1
```

And then, please, execute this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

I had a similar problem and solved by using this commands.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was admin rights issue on my corporate network, because my account has limited access even with sudo. I'm reinstalling my computer with full admin rights